# getJSON length in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to set an input value to the length of JSON file

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" id="myInput">
```

jQuery:

```
$('#myInput').val(($.getJSON("myJSON.json").length+1).toString());
```

I receive NaN always.

Comment: [`getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) returns a thenable/promise not the data retrieved from that url

Answer (score 1):

`$.getJSON` is **asynchronous**, and no need to invoke the `toString()` method. The data received is not necessarily a string (it is not the JSON, but the parsed JSON).

```
$.getJSON("myJSON.json").then(data =>
  $('#myInput').val(data.length + 1)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

```
$.getJSON("myJSON.json", function(data){
    $('#myInput').val(data.length);
});
```